# DISM doesn't work for Windows Vista image

Tags: windows-vista, dism, wim

I was trying to add the Spanish language pack and remove the English LP to Windows Vista Ultimate x64 SP2 iso file.

Some info that will help you to answer:

- The OS installed on my PC is Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1
- The OS in the `.iso` file is Windows Vista Ultimate x64 SP2
- I'm using the DISM tool v6.1 from WAIK.

I've mounted the `install.wim` file into a folder successfully, the issue starts here:

I've typed the command `dism /Image:mountedfolder /Get-Packages` and dism outputs this:

```
The command specified is unknown or not supported when running DISM.exe against a Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 or a Windows Server 2008 target image.

For more information, see the Help documentation available in the Windows Automated Installation Kit <Windows-AIK> or the Windows OEM Preinstallation Kit <OPK>.
```

It seems dism is not compatible with Windows Vista images.

Could DISM work with Windows Vista images? Is there an alternative for dism? Is there some way to add LPs without downloading third-party software (except Microsoft tools)?

Comment: I think you need to use pkgmgr.exe on Vista, not DISM. Version 6.1 corresponds to Windows 7. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748979(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @BrianC I'll try and check if pkgmgr fits my needs

Comment: @BrianC I tried and pkgmgr doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for `imagex.exe` and `peimg.exe`.

The lowest DISM version was made for Windows 7. If you need to do the same with Windows Vista, you could use WAIK for Vista, for example `imagex.exe`, `intlcfg.exe`, `pkgmgr.exe` and `peimg.exe`. If you're managing packages, I recommend `peimg.exe` it'll fit your exact needs.

If you downloaded the LPs from Vistalizator, check out http://www.froggie.sk/download/langadd64.cmd and http://www.froggie.sk/download/langlist64.cmd these commands are made for Windows Vista. If you don't want to use third-party tools, you can read these command files and learn how to use `peimg.exe`.

The equivalent of `/Get-Packages` in `peimg.exe` is.

```
peimg.exe /list path\to\your\mounted\wim
```

The equivalent of `/Add-Package` in `peimg.exe` is (the following example is based on your question and your needs).

```
"%WAIK%\Tools\PETools\peimg.exe" /import=path\to\your\lp.cab path\to\your\mounted\wim
"%WAIK%\Tools\PETools\peimg.exe" /install=*LanguagePack* path\to\your\mounted\wim
```

To mount/dismount your ISO, use `imagex.exe`.